# Mongo Repository spring data giving null pointer on saving list of objects

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a `Spring-Boot` with Mongo application where I am trying to persist a list of object.

I have a method which parses some json data and creates a list of objects. I then call the `save` method of `MongoRepository` to save it all in a go.

The Repository code looks like:

```
public interface TicketRepository extends MongoRepository<Ticket, String> {

}
```

And `Ticket` object POJO is:

```
@Document
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String topic;
    private String type;
    private long brand;
    private long group;
    private String priority;
    private String status;
    private String created_date;
    private String created_time;
    private String channel;

    public Ticket() {
    }

    //.........getters and setters....

}
```

Now, some of the fields for some objects would be null as well because I do not set any values for them.

And finally, this is how I save them:

```
@RestController
public class TicketController {

    @Autowired
    TicketRepository ticketRepository;

    @GetMapping("/tickets")
    public void saveTicketData() {
        List<Ticket> tickets = null;
        try {
            tickets = getTicketObjectList(ticketJson);
            ticketRepository.save(tickets);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            System.out.println("duplicate found!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

This throws `NullPointerExcetion` on save method call without any further stacktrace.

What could be the cause?

Comment: interface should be annotated with @Repository

Comment: I figured out the solution. Actually, the `TicketRepository` bean was not getting autowired somehow.

Comment: @roger_that : Hey I'm facing the same issue. Could you please let me know how you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

the problem i think in autowiring not in  @Repository  or even in EnableJpaRepositories. according to this answer

[Spring data repository works without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45730111/spring-data-repository-works-without-annotations)
you willn't need to mention annotation because it is auto configuration in starting point , autowiring like this

```
@Autowired
TicketRepository ticketRepository;

//getter and setter
```

Comment: Its not mandatory i believe!! You can also use `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.my.pkg")`.

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories is for just component scan for different packages (different packages mean that these packages are not under the same that contains your starting point main method )   , but Repository or controller or component or service  is marking that there will be created from  this  ,  so in our case i should put annotation for this to enable creating object to be usable

Comment: I figured out the solution. Actually, the `TicketRepository` bean was not getting autowired somehow. It works with or without the annotation.

Comment: @roger_that how can you  use its object without creating this object ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the application in debug, and breaking at the point where you call `ticketRepository.save(tickets)`?

It is possible that the tickets `List` is null.  You haven't show what the `getTicketObjectList` method does, but it could be returning a null object, rather than an actual `List`. Therefore the NPE could be because you are trying to save a null.

Alternatively it could be that the `ticketRepository` is null, and has not been auto wired correctly, but I think you would have had an exception from spring when the application starts up if that were the case.

Comment: I figured out the solution. Actually, the `TicketRepository` bean was not getting autowired somehow.