# Field personRepositary in () required a bean of type () that could not be found

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp

I am trying to run a spring developed web app and I'm getting the following error.

[image]

My folder structure is as follows.

[image]

Here is my PersonRepositary.java code which is inside the repositary folder.

```
package com.travelx.travelx.repositary;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.travelx.travelx.models.Person;

public interface PersonRepositary extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {

}
```

The RegisterController.java file which is in the controllers folder is ac follows.

```
package com.travelx.travelx.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.travelx.travelx.models.Person;
import com.travelx.travelx.repositary.PersonRepositary;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("register")
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepositary personRepositary;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public String registerPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
        personRepositary.save(person);
        return "You are Registered!";
    }

}
```

And the TravelXApplication.java file which is in the controllers is below.

```
package com.travelx.travelx.controllers;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class TravelxApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TravelxApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to make a web page where a person can register to a site. Here, I'm using xampp as my platform to handle the back end. As shown in the image, the controllers, repositories and and models are implemented in separate folders. I'm new to Spring. So no matter how hard I to find what the problem is, I cant seem to find it. Can some one help me please?

**--------------UPDATE------------------**

I've moved my  TravelXApplication.java to the com.travelx.travelx and now this error is gone.Spring works fine. However when I open my form, insert data and try to save it, the browser gives me the following error.

[image]

How do I solve it?

Comment: Try adding `error.whitelabel.enabled=false` to your application.properties file. If your Spring Boot version >= 1.3 then use `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` instead.

Comment: Please attach as well any log from your application when you get that error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PersonRepositary` is not registered as a [bean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean) in your Spring context. In practice, this means that Spring is not be able to inject it in your `RegisterController`.

I suspect that `@EnableJpaRepositories`,  `@EntityScan` and `@ComponentScan` are unnecessary in your main application class and are actually causing Spring automatic configuration to be overridden. Try deleting these three annotations from `TravelxApplication`.
Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730171/8507311) to why it should still work without annotations.

**Update:** just noticed that your `TravelxApplication` is located in the *controllers* package, but then it won't have visibility to your repository. Make sure to move your main class to the `com.travelx.travelx` package.

Comment: How can I register my PersonRepositary as a bean?

Comment: You can annotate PersonRepositary with `@Repository` so it's registered as a bean.